# I have some errors in flutter installation

Tags: flutter

I need some help in solving this problem in flutter installation

i Installed flutter put when running flutter doctor show an error

./flutter/bin/flutter: line 46: /c/src/flutter/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/pub: No such file or directory
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (8 tries left)

Comment: Flow this step? 
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Answer (score 34):

Go inside flutter SDK

you have to delete the cache folder inside bin and it will help you.

Thanks!

Comment: If like me you forgot where the flutter SDK is, it's a zip you downloaded and extracted to your chosen location. So your preffered ~/downloads ~/repos ~/dev ~/projects etc...

Comment: This answer helped me. I was trying to run flutter doctor in ubuntu installed on phone via Andronix. Apparently deleting the cache and installing curl via apt enables flutter to download dart for arm64.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know whether u downloaded git or not, cloned it or not 
so I recommend u to follow step by step as directed on this site-
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows
and the question u asked can be solved if u copy the location of flutter.bin which is located in flutter directory after cloning git, and set path of that particular files in environment variables.
you can find environment variables on right clicking on this pc icon >properties>advanced system setting>environment variables>click on path if dont have create a new path,if having select it >edit >and paste location there.
run flutter doctor.
that's it.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, when I cancel the flutter upgrade in the middle of using an **Android Studio** then the flutter becomes unreadable again, then when I when the flutter in the terminal will be like this:

> ... flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart: No such file or directory

then the solution is quite easy.

> 1. go to where the directory folder is / flutter / bin / cache /
> 2. Delete the dart-sdk folder
> 3. rename the dart-sdk.old folder to dart-sdk only

finished, your flutter is working again.